# lodash: v3.10.1 not compatible with v2.4.1. How to make backward compatible?

Tags: lodash

Came across a following difference:
Example 1

```
var s = [];
var anArray = [1,2,3];
var iterateeFunction = function(n){
       s.push(n);
}

_( anArray ).forEach( iterateeFunction )
```

***Output:***

- v2.4.1 : s = ***[1,2,3]***
- v3.10.1: s = ***[]***

Example 2

```
_.first([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

***Output:***

- v2.4.1 : ***[ 1, 2 ]***
- v3.10.1: ***1***

*Not sure if this is really an incompatibility! @John-David Dalton: Please Advise: What was the need to change this? Compatibility issues just for this! I dont think its a sufficient cause.*

This may be incorrect way of using lodash but on older versions it anyways worked.
I think there may be more such instances. So My question is

1. **Are there anymore such instances? How big a risk it is, to change my project's current version to the latest version?**
2. **how to tackle such issues such that older functionalities remain intact + I also get to use the newer utility functions in v3.10.1?**

*I really like v3.10.1 and I would love to upgrade!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This difference has to do with the [new *lazy sequences* added in version 3](http://gajus.com/blog/4/harder-better-faster-stronger-lo-dash-v3).

The result is that `each/forEach` processing, which are used for side-effects, has lead to much confusion and "bug" reports - see  ["Lazy each should cause immediate evaluation"](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/785), ["Each doesn't execute callbacks when wrapped"](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/921), etc.

**The change to *lazy sequence* processing *may break* any sequence-operation callback that *expected immediate execution*** (ie. performed a side-effect) that is not otherwise immediately forced or materialized. The problem will most often be encountered in `each/forEach` usage - where the pass-through sequence is generally ignored - but it can also manifest in other 'unexpectedly delayed' executions.

To make the v3 code act as before, force or "unwrap" the sequence with [value](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-value).

```
   _( anArray ).forEach( iterateeFunction ).value()
//   ^-- creates lazy sequence
//              ^-- so this doesn't "run" the callback
//                                          ^-- until unwrapped
```

or, better, use the non-wrapped form:

```
_( anArray, iterateeFunction )
```

or, better, with ES5-compatible functions (where it is *an array* as the object):

```
anArray.forEach(iterateFunction)
```

Comment: yes. But how many more such incompatibilities would I come across and make fixes like above?

Comment: Do you suggest me to move ahead and increase lodash version and that there would be very minor risk, if any?

Comment: It's your code. You'll need to stress it through tests. There are a number of articles that cover breaking changes such as http://gajus.com/blog/4/harder-better-faster-stronger-lo-dash-v3 - honestly, this change was probably "the most subtle breaking change".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I was searching for this only :). Will go through this now.

Comment: Please modify your answer with this link so that i can accept it :)